# Select ID from costumers that do not have contacts last 7 days and 2 times in the month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables: custumer, c_contact. 
c_contact is all the e-mails I send to my custumers.
From now on I need to put a new rule that the costumer can't receive a new e-mail if: 
1) It received an e-mail in the last 7 days
2) Have 2 or more e-mails sent in the current month

I thought something like that:

```
SELECT * 
from costumer c inner join c_contact cc on cc.ID = c.ID 
WHERE ID not in (select ID 
                 from c_contact c1 
                 where c1.ID = cc.ID 
                   and c1.CONTDATE >= getdate()-7)   
  AND ID not in (select count(ID) 
                 from c_contact 
                 where MONTH(contdate) = MONTH(getdate()) 
                   and YEAR(contdate) = YEAR(getdate()) 
                 HAVING count(ID) >= 2)
```

But the table c_contact is huge and it taking ages to run this.
Is there a way to do these 2 conditions in 1 "ID not in"? I thing it will run a lot faster.

Comment: I don't follow a having without a group by.  And even with a group by I don't understand that having.

Comment: `HAVING` without `GROUP BY` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @DanielHutmacher could you tell me what YEAR(getdate() HAVING count(ID) >= 2) does in that statement.

Comment: @Frisbee, he's missing a parenthesis after getdate() - I think his intention is to isolate rows where contdate is the same year and month as getdate(). The `HAVING` clause ensures that the number of rows (`count(ID)`) returned by the query are at least two. However, among other things, he forgot to correlate (i.e. join on) the ID column.

Comment: @Antonio, while "ID not in" is not optimal for performance reasons, there are other issues that probably have a greater impact on performance. Please see my proposed answer below for more details.

Comment: @Antonio, can you confirm that the customer ID column in `c_contact` is called ID? Sounds like it should perhaps be called CustomerID or something like that.

Comment: This part seems wrong, too: `AND ID not in (select count(ID) ...` The query as it is, would never run. (the `ID` is ambiguous in the `WHERE`, too.)

Answer (score 3):

These are the customers that have *not* received an e-mail in the last 7 days AND have received *less than* two e-mails this month:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer AS c
WHERE c.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID        --- the customer ID
    FROM c_contact
    WHERE contdate>=DATEADD(day, -31, SYSDATETIME()) -- for optimization
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING MAX(contdate)>=DATEADD(day, -7, SYSDATETIME()) OR
           SUM((CASE WHEN contdate>=DATEFROMPARTS(
               YEAR(SYSDATETIME()),
               MONTH(SYSDATETIME()),
               1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))>=2);
```

Conversely, here are customers that *have* receive an e-mail in the last 7 days OR have received *two or more* e-mails this month:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer AS c
WHERE c.ID IN (
    SELECT ID        --- the customer ID
    FROM c_contact
    WHERE contdate>=DATEADD(day, -31, SYSDATETIME()) -- for optimization
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING MAX(contdate)>=DATEADD(day, -7, SYSDATETIME()) OR
           SUM((CASE WHEN contdate>=DATEFROMPARTS(
               YEAR(SYSDATETIME()),
               MONTH(SYSDATETIME()),
               1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))>=2);
```

Because I've put the two conditions in a single `HAVING` clause, the two queries only scan the c_contact table once, making them much more efficient. In particular, an optimal index for this type of query would probably look something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX indexName ON c_contact (ID, contdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have test data:i cant test the query myself.Can you try below query

```
SELECT * from 
costumer c
 inner join 
c_contact cc 
on cc.ID = c.ID 
WHERE
not exists(select  1 from c_contact c1 where c1.ID = cc.ID
 and 
c1.CONTDATE >= getdate()-7) AND
not exists (select 1 from c_contact where MONTH(contdate) = MONTH(getdate()) 
and YEAR(contdate) = YEAR(getdate() HAVING count(ID) >= 2)
```